# Announcing a moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Computational Science Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **May 6** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on May 6, users can [nominate themselves](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On May 13, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 21.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: *If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.* Isn't this suggestion the complete opposite of how a Q&A site like Stack Exchange should work? What is the advantage of proceeding in this way rather than asking separate questions?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: An answer here pings me. ;-) If you want to ask a question on meta and ping me in a comment here, that works too.

Comment: You watching the tag "election" would work, too. I thought community managers already monitored at least some tags in all meta sites, by the way.