# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Computational Science's [first moderator election](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the new moderator is:

[image: Anton Menshov]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Geoff Oxberry who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this was [a special election](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/announcing-a-moderator-election), there was no need for a competitive vote.

Answer (score 7):

I am very glad to become a moderator for Computational Science SE. Will try my best to be a good one. In addition to the routine moderator work, I am certainly interested in making Computational Science SE more convenient, friendly to use, and, potentially/probably, attract a bigger audience.

I certainly would initiate [a tag cleanup](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/20688) (I hope @GertVdE would join me and other moderators) soon.

Continuous revision/refection of ["on-/off-topic for our community"](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/revisiting-our-off-topic-policy) is also among the items I am going to watch out for.

I personally love to work on the old questions (there are some gems among the unanswered) and will continue this effort.

I welcome all the suggestions and ideas you have. To share them, I would encourage you to use this Meta. And if you are really-really anxious for privacy, it's not too hard to find my contacts as I use my real name and list a personal website on my SE profile page.

Comment: Congratulations! I'm convinced you'll do a good job! And yes, let me know when you're ready to do some tag cleaning...